# Load custom keybindings not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have a file `custom-keybindings.dconf` that has been generated (particularly in Ubuntu 16.04) by dumping the keybindings using the command

```
dconf dump /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/ > ./config/custom-keybindings.dconf
```

I tried to load into the custom keybindings on Ubuntu 18.04 by running

```
dconf load /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/ < ./custom-keybindings.dconf
```

The problem is that the shortcuts are not actually loaded: after running the command above, the shortcuts do not work, and no shortcut is shown under "Custom Shortcuts" in `Devices > Keyboard`, on the graphical interface.

Strangly though, after running

```
dconf dump /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/
```

on the fresh Ubuntu 18.04 installation, I can see the same output of the file that was loaded. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by adding the same number of custom shortcuts I had before as "dumb" shortcuts in the graphical interface, e.g.,

[image]

and then reloading the file, i.e., running

```
dconf load /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/ < ./custom-keybindings.dconf
```

However, this is obviously not ideal, and I think should be reported as a bug (in case I am not doing anything incorrect by using this import method).

Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue on fedora and found the solution.

Dumping the "custom-keybindings" directory is not enough. You need to dump the "media-keys" directory instead as there is an extra line in it that is needed for the custom keybindings to be loaded properly.

Here is an example

```
$ dconf dump /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/
[/]
custom-keybindings=['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/']

[custom-keybindings/custom0]
binding='<Primary><Alt>t'
command='gnome-terminal'
name='Terminal'

[custom-keybindings/custom1]
binding='<Primary><Shift>Escape'
command='gnome-system-monitor'
name='System Monitor'
```